# ruby on rails select form helper Null values validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a client table (with fields id, name) and a project table (with fields id, name, client_id).

My project model is:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I need to display in one selection list the client name and the project name.
**In the following code everything is working well**, and I get in the selection list the client name concatenated with the project name (for example: IBM PROJECT_DEMO)

```
 select('hour','project_id',
        @projects.collect{ |project|
          [project.client.name+project.name,project.id]})
```

**The problem begin when I have a project without a client** in this case I get the error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried to insert an if statement in order to check the client name existence
like this

```
select('hour','project_id',
       @projects.collect{ |project|
         [project.client.name if project.client+project.name,project.id]},
       {:prompt => 'Select Project'})
```

but it not working and I get an error

I will be most appreciate if someone could give me some solution to this problem

Thanks

Comment: @Codeglot: yes i am with you...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a validation so the name cannot be nil

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

or have a default value so it is always not

```
change_column :projects, :name, :string, :default => "Sam"
```

but if you just want it to work you can do this

```
select('hour','project_id', @projects.collect{|p|["#{p.client.name if !p.client.blank?}", p.id]})
```

It won't matter if the name is nil because you can call nil but you cannot call `nil.attribute` and that is why my solution didn't work the first round.

Comment: The client id is not a must field so i have some projects with client and some projects without a client. because of that i cannot use the validates_presence_of :name solution. I copied and past your third solution <%=select('hour','project_id', @projects.collect{|p|["#{p.client.name if !p.client.name.blank?}", p.id]})%> but i still get the error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Oh, that's because the nil object is the client, not the name. I updated the code

Comment: Thanks
Great!! It is working now after the correction
Thanks very much